# Защита от взлома лицензии

Tags: javascript, php, linux, nginx, docker

Я сейчас занимаюсь разработкой сервиса для работы с учетом финансов компании, я хочу его продавать по месячной подписке, при этом мне нужно размещать продукт на машине клиентов, то есть они с помощью скрипта для установки всё автоматически сами установят, после откроют сайт и введут лицензионный ключ. Вопрос в том как защитить продукт от того чтобы оттуда не вырезали лицензию? Код будет обфусцирован, но вот где хранить данные о лицензии, чтобы клиент не мог ничего изменить. Была идея запускать приложение в докере, и запрещать рут доступ на самой машине. Вы могли бы мне что-то порекомендовать?

Comment: Никак. Если у клиента есть контроль над своей машиной — он сможет её подшаманить так, чтобы обмануть проверку лицензии, было бы желание.

Comment: Если есть шанс перегнать часть javascript в webassembly, то можно сделать такую кашу, что клиенты её не возьмутся ломать - это будет намного сложнее чем работать с JS.

Comment: у меня серверная часть на php

Comment: Онлайн проверка лицензии.

Comment: @donRumata достаточно заменить функцию запуска онлайн-проверки на функцию, всегда возвращающую успех, и программа будет работать вообще без интернета

Comment: @andreymal, ты щас описал просто любой взлом. Вообще любой. Ты хочешь сказать, что Денуво и Старфорс - прям помогли? Прям имба?

Comment: @donRumata вот поэтому в первом комментарии и написано «никак»